# Reference Request: Best practices for urban commuting

Tags: commuter

I'm thinking about commuting by bicycle for the first time. What are some resources (e.g. books, websites) I should take a look at for tips and best practices to follow.
I'm looking for further reading that contains the type of advice given in this question:

[What do you wish someone had told you before your first commute?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-do-you-wish-someone-had-told-you-before-your-first-commute)

Comment: There are 33 answers to that question, some upvoted fairly heavily. What are you hoping to get as answers to this question that were not appropriate to that question?

Comment: Generally speaking, questions asking for a list are frowned upon on SE sites and this one may get closed. That said, some have been allowed to stand. Just FYI.  http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/633/lets-talk-about-list-question-cleanup

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! It would be better to figure what specific things you want to know, and ask multiple focused questions.

Answer (score 1):

Oldie but goodie: [Effective Cycling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262560704) by John Forester.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best online reference I know:

John Allen's Bicycling Street Smarts:

http://www.bikexprt.com/streetsmarts/usa/index.htm

(there is a left-lane version for the UK)