# Speed and Cadence Bike Sensor Opinions

Tags: accessories, speed, cadence, sensor

I'm looking to start tracking my speed and cadence for my iOS app, [Cycle Meter.](http://www.abvio.com/2011/10/12/ant-advice/)  The app works great for distance, time, but is not accurate at all for measuring my speed.

So I'm thinking of buying a Garmin or a Wahoo speed/cadance sensor and wanted to get the community's opinion on the two.  I'm not worried about price.  More about quality, functionality.

The two in question are:

http://www.wahoofitness.com/Products/Wahoo-Fitness-Premium-Speed-and-Cadence-Bike-Sensor.asp

https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?pID=1266

**Update:**  been using the Wahoo one for a few weeks now and have to say that I'm very happy with it.  I've been in a lot of rain as well with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the Garmin one (came with my Edge 500) and after about 6 months it died on me. After some reading it seems that the Garmin version is only water resistant. Living just outside of Vancouver BC I get a bunch of rain and ride in lots of wet. I even took it apart and the little screw that attaches the arm has no sealing so water just gets in.

https://forums.garmin.com/showthread.php?p=89392

I now have the Wahoo sensor and have about 600km on it. It works fine and was easy to set up. I can't really give you long term use feedback but at this point I'd get another one instead of the Garmin.

Comment: I ran a couple of the garmin cadence sensors on two bikes year round in Vancouver for many years without any issue what so ever. Not sure what happened to yours.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Garmin, originally with my iPhone, and since with my Garmin Edge 800.

There's really nothing to discuss, it's been solid for at least 4 years, requires no set up, and just works, at least in my experience. I use the Wahoo iPhone dongle, when I use it for my iPhone, and when I use the iPhone to set up my power meter crank set.

Both work well.

I didn't find using the iPhone to be all that practical to use as a bike computer, and the cost of the sensors and dongles and cases was just about the same as the dedicated Edge 800 by the time all was said and done.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. yeah, see that's my issue.  i spent 4.99 on the app. so if i just get the sensors and a belt case for my iphone (http://www.ifitnessinc.com/index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=4) then i should be gtg. i always like to listen to music while i ride so i doubt i need to shell out 250+ for the edge devices.  trying to be frugal and all.  though, i always have to remember to charge my iphone :\

Comment: My experience was that I spent $400+ trying to make iPhone work, and waterproof. And then it was huge on my bike. I wasn't happy with it at all. Bought the Edge 800, spent another $400, but it's compact, efficient, and waterproof. For music I use an iPod nano plugged in to a set of headphone speakers in my helmet. Loud enough, but nothing in my ears, so it's legal, and I can hear traffic when it matters. Battery life on the Edge 800 isn't too much better than the iPhone, but with no phone/music/app drainage it last 3 days or so between charges. All in all, much happier with the Garmin.

Comment: interesting.  headphone speakers in your helmet?  do you have a link?  man, when i have my earbuds in, i can't hear anything but music, which i know is not safe, so i'm open to other options.. sometimes i leave one earbud out but i loose out on the music quality.

Comment: No links. I made my own, using the bits from a cheap set of Bluetooth over the ear speakers. They hang on the helmet straps, just below/behind my ears, and they're wireless, which is nice, although I do have to plug in my helmet to charge them.

Comment: Also, check this out. I'm sponsoring it. Please join me. I'd love to see it get into production. http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1294096266/sleek-speak-wireless-speakers-for-your-bike?ref=live

Answer (score 2):

Fady listening to music while riding is probably the most dangerous thing you can do so do not explore that idea please.. With that said I use the edge 500 and it has loads of functionality and will most likely support all your needs. You will usually need to purchase a speed/ cadence sensor with it. Battery life is great so long as you have it set to turn off with inactivity. I do still carry my phone in my jersey pocket when out alone just in case somethin happens.

Comment: welcome to stackexchange joe!  yeah, i know.  i'm willing to take my chances..i do ride sport bikes, so it's in my blood to be dangerous, i guess. glad you could join the conversation :)

Comment: check out the discussion on listening to music while riding: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/623/is-listening-to-music-dangerous-while-cycling